# Driver INF File: Identifying supported OS Architecture from driver inf file

Tags: driver, inf

I am trying to parse INF file of drivers in my code to identify the OS architecture supported by them. For this I'm referring to the **"INF MANUFACTURER SECTION"** link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547454(v=vs.85).aspx

I have an Driver INF File which has a manufacturer section as:

[Manufacturer]

%HSD%=HSD,NTAMD64

according to the manufacturer section documentation given in the above link, the INF Model Section name must be decorated with the supported architecture and hence, **"NTAMD64"** suggests that the Driver is valid for a 64-bit Windows Operating System. 
But what does **"HSD"** suggest?

Which operating system does it refer to? How to indentify this?

Answer (score 0):

HSD is a section identifier, it has nothing to do with a target OS. NTAMD64 indicates the OS.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes that truly is the section identifier, but PNP IDs mentioned under [HSD] would be applicable to 32-bit Windows OS or 64-bit Windows OS? How to identify that?

Comment: 64. That's what NTAMD64 is for. Your section tag should be decorated with it: [HSD.NTAMD64]

Comment: if we go by the norm, for HSD and NTAMD64, we can have two model sections. One would be [HSD] and the other would be [HSD.NTAMD64]. Both the sections would contain PNP Ids. I can understand that PNP Ids contained inside [HSD.NTAMD64] would be used for a 64-bit OS. But what about the PNP Ids contained within [HSD]. What architecture does it imply?

Comment: @MayankSehgal If I'm not mistaken that will cover rest of the OSs that aren't specified by sections with decorations.

Comment: OK. So that would mean the lone [HSD] section would be applicable to all the OS and both architectures. right?

Comment: I think so. You can get a more authorized answer at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/threads